# your 131072x1 screen size is bogus. expect trouble al pulsar F6 en Visual Studio Code

Tags: vscode

Estoy empezando a programar en c y vi un video en el cual en VSC puedes compilar usando la tecla f6 (tengo entendido que es una extensión), sin embargo a la hora de apretar dicha tecla, me aparece esto:

> your 131072x1 screen size is bogus. expect trouble

¿Qué hago?

Comment: Debes instalar la extensión `c/c++` de Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Puedes buscar esto como shortcuts - atajos, en vscode por defecto viene es <kbd>F5</kbd> para correr y depurar o <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> para solo correr.